Does the mouthpiece of the shofar have to be at the tip of the horn?
This Irish ram's horn has a hole bored in the middle of the horn. Is this acceptable as a shofar or does it count as a hole in the shofar?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RITlXgK0OZY



Interesting. AFAIK there's no rule where the mouthpiece must be.

Well we know it can't be blown from the wider side . Very good question

One needs to see if the stream of air creating the sound is singular, not broken into two to create the higher pitch. It can be that when blowing, one part of air flow just exits the shofar and the other bounces off the dead end and we hear a mixture of two voices. It appears to work like a flute, not clarnet.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%95_%D7%96

Interesting question! I could not find this question addressed directly with the little bit of research that I did, but I assume that it's not good.
A different shofar "hack" is discussed in Shulchan Aruch (OC 586:12):

הפכו ותקע בו לא יצא בין הפכו כדרך שהופכין החלוק שהחזיר פנימי לחיצון
בין שהניחו כמו שהיה אלא שהרחיב את הקצר וקיצר את הרחב וה"ה אם תקע במקום
הרחב פסול (ר"ן פ"ב דר"ה): ‏



If one inverted it, he has not fulfilled his obligation, whether he inverts it like one inverts a shirt, flipping the inside and the
outside, or whether one leaves it as it was but widens the narrow side
and narrows the wide side. Similarly, if one blows through the wide
side, it is not kosher (Ra"n chapter 2 of Rosh Hashanah).


Mishna Berura (ad loc., 60) explains:

בין הפכו כדרך וכו' - והטעם דכתיב והעברת שופר תרועה דרך העברה בעינן
דהיינו כדרך שהאיל מעבירו בראשו מחיים: ‏
Whether he inverts it etc.: The reason is because it is written "Then you shall sound (והעברת) the horn loud," which
means that it must be done in the direction of passing (דרך
העברה). That is, in the direction that the ram passes the horn while alive.

Additionally, the Ra"n (as cited in Kaf Hachayim) would likely not either support this unorthodox horn construction:

כ"כ הר"ן בפ' ראוהו ב"ד בשם הירושלמי. ויהיב סימנא מן המצר קראתי יה. ‏

The Ra"n provides a mnemonic device to recall this halacha (of not blowing from the wide end of the shofar) from the verse in Tehillim 118 "In distress (מצר; literally, "narrow place") I called on the LORD."
Although not directly addressed in these sources, it seems reasonable to me to assume that the reasonings of דרך העברה and מן המצר would also invalidate a shofar that is blown from a hole in the middle of the horn.
